# How to get string from HTML with regex?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse block from html page so i try to `preg_match` this block with php

```
if( preg_match('<\/div>(.*?)<div class="adsdiv">', $data, $t))
```

but doesn't work

```
</div>

blablabla

blablabla

blablabla

<div class="adsdiv">
```

i want grep only `blablabla blablabla` words
any help

Comment: please, describe exactly what html text you would like to match?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what has been said above, also add the `/s` modifier so `.` will match newlines. (edit: as Alan kindly pointed out, `[^<]+` will match newlines anyway)

I always use `/U` as well since in these cases you normally want minimal matching by default. (will be faster as well). And `/i` since people say `<div>`, `<DIV>`, or even `<Div>`...

```
if (preg_match('/<\/div>([^<]+)<div class="adsdiv">/Usi', $data, $match))
{
    echo "Found: ".$match[1]."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Not found<br>";
}
```

**edit** made it a little more explicit!

Comment: thanks mvds for reply but it reply with empty result meaning not work

Comment: Ok I added a little code which shows how to get the matched portion out of it. This should work (although, it requires that the input is *exactly* what you are showing; i.e. not some formatted html by firefox-like "view source"!)

Comment: `[^<]` will match newlines whether you use the `/s` modifier or not.

Comment: And I recommend NOT getting in the habit of using the `/U` modifier.  It's better to get *out of* the habit of using `.*`.  Reluctant quantifiers speed up matching by avoiding excessive backtracking, but you already took care of that by using `[^<]+` instead of `.*`.  If anything, the `/U` is slowing you down, because character-for-character, reluctant quantifiers are slower than greedy ones.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex aint the right tool for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Here is how to do it with DOM

```
$html = <<< HTML
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <p>previous div<p>
    </div>
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
    <div class="adsdiv">
        <p>other content</p>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
```

Content in an HTML Document is TextNodes. Tags are ElementNodes. Your TextNode with the content of blablabla has to have a parent node. For fetching the TextNode value, we will assume you want all the TextNode of the ParentNode of the `div` with `class` attribute of `adsdiv`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@class="adsdiv"]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    foreach($node->parentNode->childNodes as $child) {
        if($child instanceof DOMText) {
            echo $child->nodeValue;
        }
    };
}
```

Yes, it's not a funky one liner, but it's also much less of a headache and gives you solid  control over the HTML document. Harnessing the Query Power of XPath, we could have shortened the above to

```
$nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@class="adsdiv"]/../text()');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

I kept it deliberatly verbose to illustrate how to use DOM though.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)** - If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters,
>   including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier
>   is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always
>   matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this
>   modifier.

So, the following should work:

```
if (preg_match('~<\/div>(.*?)<div class="adsdiv">~s', $data, $t))
```

The `~` are there to delimit the regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

You need to delimit your regex; use `/<\/div>(.*?)<div class="adsdiv">/` instead.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve the OP's problem, this *is* a valid point. The regex in the question lacks delimiters and will throw an exception if you try to use it.