# PHP replace string

Tags: php, string

`$name` (string) gives something like (possible value):

```
John II, Litten Draw
```

We should update `$name` in two steps:

1. Catch the words before first comma and throw them to the end of the string
2. Remove first comma
3. *Create a file* `current_name.txt` (or update if already exists) and throw to it source of `$name`

"John II, Litten Draw" should be replaced with "Litten Draw John II".

Thanks.

Comment: Do these names from the "current_name.txt" file? (And if so are they one per line?)

Comment: Is this a Homework assigment?

Comment: @Fernando no, it's a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440442/php-external-page

Comment: @middaparka $name always has just one name (its a string, not an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that should work OK:

```
<?php

    function getCanonicalName($name) {

        // Check for the existance of a comma and swap 'elements' if necessary.
        if(strpos($name, ',') !== false) {
            list($surname, $forename) = explode(',', $name);
            $name = $forename . ' ' . $surname; 
        }

        // Trim the name.
        return trim($name);
    }   


    // Test data and file I/O.
    $outputData = '';
    $testData = array('Obama, Barak', 'Federer, Roger', 'John Parker');

    foreach($testData as $name) {
        $outputData .= getCanonicalName($name) . "\n";
    }


    file_put_contents('current_name.txt', $outputData, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Incidentally, this (like all of the solutions currently attached to your question) will cause data loss if there's more than one comma in $name. As such, if this is possible you should update getCanonicalName to cater for this eventuality.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
$split = explode(",", $name, 1);
$name = trim($split[1]) . " " . trim(split[0]);
```

Then it's just [basic file I/O](http://www.ozzu.com/php-tutorials/tutorial-basic-php-file-t95992.html).

If you have a list of words (assuming they are all on separate lines):

```
$list = explode("\n", $names);
$nnames = "";
foreach($list as $name)
{
        $split = explode(",", $name);
        $nnames .= trim($split[1]) . " " . trim(split[0]) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `file_put_contents` = easy way to dump string to file

Comment: @Ignatz: No. This will work with one word pair. I'll update to work with a list deliminated by a newline (`\n`).

Comment: @Josh K seems a missunderstand. Sorry, have updated the question

Comment: Where does it say he wants it using regex?  Also update your answer Josh to `split(",", $name, 1)` so it splits only the first comma

Comment: @stereofog: Regular expressions aren't needed here.

Comment: @Ignatz: Works fine for me. Note you have to handle the file I/O yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should do it for you...

```
preg_replace('#\\b(\\w+),\\s*(\\w+)\\b#', '\\2 \\1', $string);
```

Basically, it's looking for:

1. A word boundry (the `\\b` part)
2. Then one or more word characters (the `\\w+` part)
3. Then a comma followed by zero or more whitespace characters (`,\\s*`)
4. Then one or more word characters (the `\\w+` part)
5. Finally, another word boundry...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this doesn't work"?  I've tried it on my machine, and it works quite well...

Answer (score 2):

regular expressions are the way to go here

```
$a = "Obama, Barak";
echo preg_replace('~(\w+)\W+(\w+)~', "$2 $1", $a);
```

also works for multiple names:

```
$a = "
Obama, Barak
Federer, Roger
Dickens, Charles
";

echo preg_replace('~(\w+)\W+(\w+)~', "$2 $1", $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos) to find the comma, [`ltrim`](https://www.php.net/ltrim) to remove the whitespace, and [`fopen`](https://www.php.net/fopen) with the mode `a` to append to the file. You can also use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) to split around the comma, which is usually easier

Comment: You don't need to find the comma. Split, trim, reconcat.

Comment: @Josh Well, `explode` is "finding the comma" too, just not manually. I prefer `explode` too, but I was trying to give him exactly the bullets he asked for